# FTPServer Apache: checking if a file is uploading

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-server

I'm using FTPServer Apache for a Distributed File System project. I implemented a garbage collector that deletes files which are present on the FTPServer but not in the logical FS.

Anyway, since the upload procedure could be long, the Garbage Collector shouldn't delete files which are in the upload procedure. There is any method troguh FTPServer (or java in general) to check if a file is not totally uploaded?

**NOTE:**
The `listFiles()` method in FTPServer returns a file which is not totally uploaded yet, so it's not a feasible solution